# Recursive function does not work as desired

Tags: python, recursion

I read the attached image with `cv2.imread` and want to find the contours of the image object. If the threshold is too large, i.e. if `cv2.findContours` finds several outlines, the threshold should be reduced piece by piece so that only one contour is found at the end.
That's why I wrote the recursive function `thresholdloop`, but unfortunately it doesn't do what it should.

```
import cv2   

b = cv2.imread("test.tiff")

thresh_factor = 140


imgray_b = cv2.cvtColor(b,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret_b,thresh_b = cv2.threshold(imgray_b,thresh_factor,255,0)

_, cb, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh_b, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)


def thresholdloop(cb, thresh_factor, X):

    while X == False:
        if len(cb) > 1:
            thresh_factor = thresh_factor - 5
            ret_b, thresh_b = cv2.threshold(imgray_b, thresh_factor, 255, 0)
            _, cb, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh_b, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
            X = False
            return thresholdloop(cb, thresh_factor, X)
        else:
            X = True

X = False
thresholdloop(cb, thresh_factor, X)
```

[image: Attachment]

Comment: "Does not work" how? Should the method return something, or set some global variable, like `cb`? Right now, it seems to have to effect at all.

Comment: No, I don't get errors. The recursive function is called repeatedly until thresh_facor = 115 and len (cb)=1, but after completion of the function thresh_factor = 140 and len (cb)=2.
But I want to finish with thresh_factor = 140 and len (cb)=2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your function tries to modify global variables without using the `global` keyword. You *could* fix it by removing all the parameters from the function and instead doing

```
def thresholdloop():
    global ret_b
    global cb
    global thresh_b
    global thresh_factor
    # rest of function
```

But instead I'd suggest using a simple `while` loop in the global scope itself (i.e. no function)

```
# after first calculation of cb
while len(cb) > 1:
    thresh_factor = thresh_factor - 5
    ret_b, thresh_b = cv2.threshold(imgray_b, thresh_factor, 255, 0)
    _, cb, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh_b, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

Or like this, so you don't have to replicate the code for calculating `cb` inside the loop and before

```
b = cv2.imread("test.tiff")
thresh_factor = 145  # + 5
imgray_b = cv2.cvtColor(b,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
while True:
    thresh_factor = thresh_factor - 5
    ret_b, thresh_b = cv2.threshold(imgray_b, thresh_factor, 255, 0)
    _, cb, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh_b, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    if len(cb) == 1:
        break
```